# Не форматируется ssd

Tags: windows, ssd, diskpart

Есть ноутбук с двумя винтами:

> ```
> DISKPART> list disk
>
>  Disk ### Status     Size   Free    Dyn Gpt
>  -------- ---------- ------ ------- --- ---
>  Disk 0   Online     931 Gb     0 B      *
>  Disk 1   Online     238 Gb     0 B      *
> ```

Стояла у меня на HDD (disk0) предустановленная windows8, а небольшой SSD (disk1) я воткнул позже сам вместо DVD.

И захотел я недавно поставить на SSD винду 10, чтобы со временем снести её с HDD.

Но несколько попыток поставить винду с флешки приводили к постоянным неуспехам, хорошо хотя бы первый диск не убил. Причина -- gui разбиение разделов постоянно отказывается форматировать раздел с ошибкой

> we couldn't format the selected partition error 0x80070057

, по которой ничего внятного не предлагают.

Поэтому я уже перешёл к тому, что по советам в интернете разбиваю диски из командной строки (Shift+F10 при выборе разделов) при помощи diskpart.

Тем не менее и этим способом я получаю ошибку. Я начинаю с чистого неразмеченного диска (причём очищаю через clean all), потом создаю раздел create partition primary, а затем форматирую: либо через format fs=ntfs quick либо через format fs=ntfs

И в обоих случаях получаю ошибку (либо на 0% при quick формате, либо на 100% при полном):

> ```
> DISKPARP> format fs=ntfs
>
>   100 percent completed
>
> DiskPart has encountered an error: The parameter is incorrect.
> See the System Event Log for more information.
> ```

И собственно на этом рекомендации из интернета заканчиваются: считается, что полный clean all + полный формат спасут от этих ошибок. Не спасли.

Что делать? В какую сторону смотреть? Есть ли какой-то лог или event log во время инсталляции?

В чём я уверен, что не может быть причиной проблем:

1. Флешки нормальные, одна -- свежераспечатанная
2. Флэшки созданы через официальные инструменты microosft для подготовки установщика Windows10 https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10
3. Материнка поддерживает UEFI
4. Дело не в том, что SSD сдыхает: специально проверил при помощи CrystalDiskInfo8_3_1.exe что все показатели S.M.A.R.T. идеальны и проблем никаких нет.
5. Дело не в проблемах питания: я специально воткнул ноутбук в бесперебойник

Comment: Что мешает разбить диск на разделы в имеющейся операционке? Не забыть, что надо инициализировать диск gpt, а не в mbr.

Comment: А зачем вы вообще разбиваете диск вручную, и, тем более, вручную форматируете разделы? Выдерните HDD, загрузитесь с флешки, удалите прямо в инсталлере винды все имеющиеся разделы с SSD, и ткните в пустое неразмеченное место в качестве цели для установки. Инсталлер сам побьет на разделы.

Comment: Как и PashaPash я бы вам тоже посоветовал оставить лишь 1 ssd, загрузиться с образа установки windows и там удалить, создать раздел а после уже в установленной винде подключить старый диск, дело в том, в таком случае загрузочный сектор останется на обоих дисках и управлять загрузкой уже будет BIOS в котором можно задать приоритет дисков, тем самым вы не потеряете никак старую ОС и загрузитесь с новой где сможете всё что угодно сделать уже из под нового системного диска SSD )

Comment: Ранее я также сталкивался с проблемой удаления и создания разделов при установки с флешь носителей и тут лишь решил вопрос путем установки ОС через внешний привод с лазерного диска!

Comment: У меня достаточно кривые руки, чтобы лезть отключать винт, да и не представляю, чем поможет убрать HDD, если я его в инсталлере никак не использую. Диск я пробовал ставить в неразмеченную область, но винда на разных этапах выдаёт ошибку и не хочет ставиться (это либо момент форматироватия, либо копирования файлов на винт)

Comment: Вам нужно попробовать поставить ОС с диска, у меня так друг тоже маялся после моего совета взял у знакомого привод и всё отлично получилось, попробуйте поставить ОС с диска а не с флешки!

Comment: А можно я влезу со своим любимым `gparted live`, через который размечаю разделы вот уже 11 лет и сильных проблем вспомнить не могу? Опять же, через него разделы (и табилцы разделов) удалять - одно удовольствие.

Comment: По поводу "нафиг отрубать винт с существуюущей ОС". Согласен со сторонниками, потому что коллега в своё время поленился это сделать и винда как-то хитро то ли оставила загрузчик на винте, то ли не записала на ссд. Суть в том, что после установки - она не загружалась с ссд, если был отключен винт. В общем - я бы всё-таки дёрнул sata-кабель винта на время установки.

Comment: @donRumata да, винда попробует вписать себя в uefi раздел на hdd, и не создаст системный раздел. Потом hdd отключить - и все, ноут не загружается. Причем есть шанс что у AK сейчас именно на этом и падает :)

Comment: @AK диск там обычно под отдельной крышкой, достаточно пару болтов открутить.

Comment: А. Блин. Ноут. Я не прочитал. Ну, в любом случае я бы загнался с физическим отключением винта.